# Dompdf generated pdf is 0 bytes

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to save a pdf to disk.

I am using `Dompdf` and `Codeigniter` as below:

```
$this->load->helper('dompdf','file');
$this->load->helper('file');
$saveTo = './labels'; 
$data['id'] = $this -> uri -> segment(3);
$data['no_of_prints'] = $this -> uri -> segment(4);   
$labelname = "Label". $data['id'] ."-". $data['no_of_prints'] . ".pdf";
$html = $this->load->view('label_view', $data, TRUE);
file_put_contents($saveTo."/".$labelname, pdf_create($html, $labelname));
```

While the labelname gets generated correctly. The file saved to disk reads 0 bytes and as expected I get  an `Adobe Reader cannot open this file ...` error.

I am also using `fancybox 2.0` to popup the pdf and when I right click on the popup,(the pdf does not show, i'm guessing pdf plugin issues) I am able to `Save as` a readable pdf that is not 0 bytes.

It is important for the application to save pdf to disk automatically. How do i save a readable pdf to disk?

Comment: Does the file get written to the server? Have you tried using an absolute system path for the file location?
E.g. $save_to = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/labels/'.$labelname.'.pdf';

Comment: The files gets written to the `labels` folder in root It's just that it's 0 bytes and cannot be opened by the pdf Reader.

Comment: You should investigate in parts. First, look for any errors or warnings from PHP. Second, check to make sure `$html` is filled? You can just echo it out to check. Third, return the results of `pdf_create()` so you can make sure it's returning something. If none of that works you might need to check your dompdf configuration or dive into the extension that uses dompdf.

Comment: Thanks @BrianS checked the parts individually, used selected answer below it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found some old CI code (pre version 2) that used DomPDF, I had an extra parameter to write as a file.
Is this much different from yours?

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function pdf_create($html, $filename, $stream=FALSE, $orientation='portrait')
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper( array(0,0, 2.175 * 72, 3.375 * 72), "landscape" ); // credit card size
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream)
    {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
    }
    else
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->helper('file');
        write_file("./uploads/$filename.pdf", $dompdf->output());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Added `require_once()` , made a new object of `DOMPDF` as shown in your code and it worked.Thanks.